# Combine two multi-column dataframes into single two-column dataframe

Tags: r

I have two dataframes looking like:

Sheet1:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Sample1 | Sample2 |
| Sample3 | Sample4 |

Sheet2:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| abcd | efgh |
| ijkl | mnop |

I want to combine them together into

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Sample1 | abcd |
| Sample2 | efgh |

etc.

Basically each cell of the two sheets matches just want to put them into a single file.

Comment: Do you have more than two columns in sheet1 and sheet2?

Comment: Yes there are more than two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution using `stack()` within `data.frame()`:

```
combined <- data.frame(
  Column.A = stack(Sheet1)[, 1], 
  Column.B = stack(Sheet2)[, 1]
)

combined <- combined[order(combined$Column.A), ]
combined
```

```
  Column.A Column.B
1  Sample1     abcd
3  Sample2     efgh
2  Sample3     ijkl
4  Sample4     mnop
```

Or a slight variation using `cbind()` instead of `data.frame()`:

```
combined <- cbind(
  stack(Sheet1)[, 1, drop = FALSE], 
  stack(Sheet2)[, 1, drop = FALSE]
)

names(combined) <- names(Sheet1)
combined <- combined[order(combined$`Column A`), ]
```

```
  Column A Column B
1  Sample1     abcd
3  Sample2     efgh
2  Sample3     ijkl
4  Sample4     mnop
```